# Using R and Table function can i use 4 specific columns out of a larger dataset to create a two by two frequency table

Tags: r, frequency-table

I have a few columns

```
 Location|Yes M & M Peanuts| No M& M Peanuts | Yes M & M Almond| No M& M Almond|Location
               5                 10                 20             6                 NYC
```

I would like to do using the table function or something more convenient where i turn those columns into

```
              Yes | No
M & M Peanuts  5    10
M & M Almond   20    6
```

updated example

```
df2 <- structure(list(`Yes M & M Peanuts` = 5L, `No M & M Peanuts` = 10L, 
                      `Yes M & M Almond` = 20L, `No M & M Almond` = 6L, "Location" = "NYC"), class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, 
                               -1L))
```

Comment: [gather](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) %>% [separate](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) %>% [spread](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html)

Comment: its a column separation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with `pivot_longer`, specify the `names_pattern` to extract the value (`.value`) part to go into columns 'Yes', 'No' and another column 'grp' that extracts the suffix part of the column name.  Then, the 'grp' column can be converted to row names with `column_to_rownames`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "grp"),
        names_pattern = "(Yes|No)\\s*(.*)") %>%
  column_to_rownames('grp')
```

-output

```
#               Yes No
#M & M Peanuts   5 10
#M & M Almond   20  6
```

---

using the OP's second dataset in the updated post, we need to specify the `cols` without the 'Location'

```
df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Location, names_to = c(".value", "grp"),
    names_pattern = "(Yes|No)\\s*(.*)") %>%
  column_to_rownames('grp')
#              Location Yes No
#M & M Peanuts      NYC   5 10
#M & M Almond       NYC  20  6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Yes M & M Peanuts` = 5L, `No M & M Peanuts` = 10L, 
    `Yes M & M Almond` = 20L, `No M & M Almond` = 6L), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: sample %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`Yes M & M Peanuts`,`No M& M Peanuts`,
                        `Yes M & M Almond`,`No M& M Almond`), names_to = c(".value", "grp"),
               names_pattern = "(Yes|No)\\s*(.*)") %>%
  column_to_rownames('grp')

Comment: doing it like that i got this error Error in get(nm, envir = fn, mode = "function") : 
  object 'column_to_rownames' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: @user35131 it is from `tibble`.  I used `packageVersion('tibble')#
[1] ‘3.0.3’`

Comment: Error: Can't subset elements that don't exist.
x Locations 1, 2, 3, and 4 don't exist.
i There are only 0 elements.

Comment: @user35131 Are you getting the same error from the data in my post.  I was just copy/pasting your data to create that data

Comment: ok nevermind. My yes was lowercase. Thank you. it worked.

Comment: I added a sample of the dataset. I didn't foresee this being an issue, ,but in the table i get the other columns from the dataset. It's not limited to the 2 by 2.

Comment: @user35131 Sorry, I didn't see any update in your post

Comment: I made an update adding an extra column in the dataset that i would not like in the final frequency table

Comment: @user35131 can you use `dput` to show that example so that it becomes easier for me to test it.

Comment: df1 <- structure(list(`Yes M & M Peanuts` = 5L, `No M & M Peanuts` = 10L, 
                      `Yes M & M Almond` = 20L, `No M & M Almond` = 6L, "Location" = "NYC"), class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, 
                               -1L))

Comment: @user35131 can you update in your post as some quotes are missing in comments

Comment: Was that how you wanted?